# How to override fields_view_get method of BaseModel class in Odoo V9? (Generic fields_view_get method)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I need to override the fields_view_get method of the BaseModel class in odoo9 and the method should be generic.

In **models.py**, fields_view_get() declared as version 7.0 standard.

I had used below basic structure:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
from openerp.osv.orm import BaseModel

def fields_view_get(self, cr, user, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False,final_result={}):

BaseModel.fields_view_get = fields_view_get
```

This code works for version 7.0 but not work in version 9.0.

Error Log:TypeError: fields_view_get() takes at least 3 arguments (5 given)

How can i do this?

Thanks,
Waiting for reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Solution. Please find this.

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class BaseModelExtend(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'basemodel.extend'
def _register_hook(self, cr):
    @api.cr_uid_context
    def fields_view_get(self, cr, user, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        #Code
    models.BaseModel.fields_view_get = fields_view_get
    return super(BaseModelExtend, self)._register_hook(cr)
```